# Comparing Date Fields in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I wanted to create a new column in my PowerBI Dashboard report that compares two date columns (<, >, >=, <=). I need the output for this new date column to either be a date or some sort of binary output (true/fasle, 1 or 0). How can I do this in a PowerBI?

Tried creating a measured column but can't convert into a date format

Comment: Can you please add the code from the measured column you are trying with?

Comment: @mkRabbani I do not have the code. They are just two date columns from 2 different Excel files I added in PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of your dates are in the same table you can create a *calculated column with a if statement*

**Check_Date = if(TableA[Column 1] = TableA[Column 2], 1, 0) change the data type for column into True/False**

If both the dates are in two different tables then you need to create a relationship between both the tables if no relationship exist then create Index for both the tables and then **build a relationship based on Index, create a calculated column** on any of the table

**Check_Date = if(TableA[Date] = RELATED(TableB[Date]),1,0) change the data type for column into True/False**